# mysql find value in string starts with double quotes

Tags: mysql

Trying to ascertain the value(s) of a single string in MySQL `table` column containing business information, including company name, tax id and city. Three records shown below depict this example:

```
custom_field
a:4:{i:1;s:9:"Some City";i:3;s:10:"Some number tax";i:4;s:0:"null for company";i:5;s:12:"Any company name";}
a:4:{i:5;s:17:"Any company name";i:1;s:8:"Some City";i:3;s:10:"Some number tax";i:4;s:0:"null for company";}
a:4:{i:5;s:77:"Any company name";i:1;s:6:"Some City";i:3;s:10:"Some number tax";i:4;s:0:"null for company";}
```

Opencart inserts these records via registration module page upon completing checkout.
The registration module puts `i:1` for `"Some City"` ,  `i:3` for `"Some number tax"` , `i:4 "null for company" , i:5 for "Any company name"

How does one go about finding the double quoted strings' value(s)?

The values are not null and they start with i:1,i:3,i:4,i:5`

Comment: cleaning it up thoroughly

Comment: This is a little tedious to do in MySQL. Is there no option for parsing the json string prior to insertion or querying the string in application code?